# OpenVPN server on DMZ router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, dmz

I am stuck with the ISP modem/roter and I want to use a second router with VPN capabilities, but I cannot get the OpenVPN server to work.

Please do not suggest to put the first router as bridge as I have tried and it is not possible.

This is My Network configuration so far:

Modem Router 1: Telstra Netgear V7610.

Gets Internet signal from a phone line (ADSL?)

It has 2 VOIP phone lines for the office.

Fix WAN IP XX.XXX.XX.XX

DHCP: ON

DHCP Range: 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200

LAN IP: 192.168.0.1

DMZ Server on: 192.168.0.3

Port forward 22523 to Router 2 on 192.168.0.3

Router 2 Asus RT AC88U

Connected to modem 1 on LAN port 1 to LAN port 1 on Asus through a switch.

Assigned LAN IP as 192.168.0.3

DHCP server OFF

OpenVPN server ON with port UDN 22523.

My question now:

1.With DMZ pointing to the Asus Router do I need to connect the ASUS router using its WAN port?

2.Do I need to setup WAN IP address of  asus as our Public IP address? or the Local IP of the V7610?

3.Since the Asus Router is in the DMZ now, Do I still need to do port forwarding port 22523 to Asus router? 192.168.0.3? or maybe this is causing an issue and I need to delete this port fwd from V7610 table?

I can connect to the open VPN server if I am in the local network. but is does not work if I am offsite (My phone hotspot).

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, connecting locally shows that the service is running on the router. Check the wan address again, go to canyouseeme.org and test your port forward, is the IP address that it shows you here different from what the modem reports as it's wan address?

Comment: Thanks Tim, i solved by port forwarding my vpn port to the Asus modem. All working now